# In Python 3.11 how can i specify a specific string that i want to be looped

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, reddit

```
def get_date(date):
    return dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)

for submission in subreddit.search(ticker, sort='hot',limit=150):
        if submission.domain != "self.AMD_Stock":
            continue
        print(submission.title)
        print('Submission ID =', submission.id, '\n')
        print('date =', get_date(submission.created_utc) , '\n')
```

This is the code i have

And it prints me this result

```
Daily Discussion Thursday 2023-06-08
Submission ID = 143ynnd 

date = 2023-06-08 06:01:25 

Daily Discussion Wednesday 2023-06-07
Submission ID = 1432puu 

date = 2023-06-07 06:01:44 

Daily Discussion Tuesday 2023-06-06
Submission ID = 1422x8w 

date = 2023-06-06 06:01:26 

Daily Discussion Monday 2023-06-05
Submission ID = 1411hks
```

And then i define a submission ID that i want to collect.

```
Post1 = reddit.submission(id='11y68k3')
```

But i want to automatize it.

I want that each post has its unique ID from the ID's i scrapped from reddit
So i would have Post1, Post2 etc.
And i want to collect all the IDs from the printed result.

I thought of creating a list with

```
Post = [ID1, "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"] 

for ID in Post :
   Post1 = reddit.submission(id='ID1')
```

But i dont know how to extract the substring from the printed result because the ID format varies and is different each time. And the position can be slightly different depending on the printed resulted before. I thought of using regex. But i dont know how to specify the exact line where the "Submission ID = 1411hks" is

Comment: Please re-read and clarify what it is you're trying to achieve... My best guess is that you'd like to loop through the submissions, and pick out any that match from a predefined list of IDs? I don't follow where or why "_the second line_" is relevant.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not clear enough. Let me rephrase it. I want to grab all the IDs from the printed result.
when i was talking about the second line, i meant that the IDs are always located on the second line like here: 
Daily Discussion Thursday 2023-06-08
Submission ID = 143ynnd

Comment: Why operate on the printed output, and not deal with the data/variables in code?... then there's no parsing or regex to deal with.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly. How can i do that ? I need to create a variable that is going to be my printed result that i will iterate in the loop ? I'm sorry to asking dumb questions, i'm new to Python